# How to use remote location property file in spring re loadable message resource in java

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-mvc

I have distributed system with 8 app servers running tomcat on it. It is a spring application. I want to use a property file which will located on some others server an all tomcat will read it from there only.
I am using ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource to use auto refreshing feature.
My bean definition is

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">  
          <property name="basenames" >
            <list>
                <value>file:///192.168.1.10//var/rateLimit</value> 
             </list>
        </property>
        <property name="cacheSeconds" value="60"></property>  
</bean>
```

and I am calling property like this

```
System.out.println(messageSource.getMessage("testProp", null, null));
```

I could not load file using this ip address.

Could you please help me on this.

Comment: <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">  
   <!--      <property name="basename" value="D:\\prop"></property>  -->
        <property name="basenames" >
   <list>
   <!-- <value>file:///D://prop</value>   -->  
       <value>file:///192.168.1.10//var/rateLimit</value> 
    </list>
   </property>
        <property name="cacheSeconds" value="60"></property>  
 </bean>

Comment: did you check that link in a browser?

Comment: Yep i checked that i can open it in browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I use to read an external properties file over HTTP:

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames" value="/WEB-INF/messages,http://our.server.org/ws/i18n"/>
    <property name="cacheSeconds" value="300"/>
    <property name="useCodeAsDefaultMessage" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

Maybe enclosing the file URI inside a `value` quoted string may help?

Comment: dear could you please suggest me one more thing asthat keeping this file at remote location would make an impact of performance on app while reading the properties.

Comment: If you set the `cacheSeconds` to -1, then it caches the file for ever. So it will only load the file once, on startup and should not impact performance. You might want to set it to some long value so changes are picked up (like daily).

Comment: Hmm cool it means if i make it at interval of 24 hours file will be loaded once in 24 hours then there will be not http connection between this time. Every app server will have cached file and will not communicate to remote server. Is it right ?